# Cannot bind value with command parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, icommand

I need get the `Text` value from `TextBox` tag in my `SubmitCommand`
but I only get an empty value. Please help me find out what I need to do for to display the text in my `MessageBox`.

```
<UserControl>
   <Grid>
      <StackPanel
         Grid.Row="1"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Margin="0"
         FocusManager.IsFocusScope="true">
         <TextBox
            Name="linkTb"   
            DataContext="{Binding SelectedSite}"                  
            IsManipulationEnabled="True"
            TabIndex="0" />
         <StackPanel                    
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
               x:Name="submitButton"                        
               Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
               CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedSite}"
               Content="Submit"/>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here I can't get text of `TextBox`:

```
public class LoginViewModel : MainViewModelBase
{
   private string selectedSite;
   public LoginViewModel(NavigationManager navigationManager) : base(navigationManager)
   {
      SubmitCommand = new RelayCommand(obj => Submit());
   }
   public RelayCommand SubmitCommand { get; set; }
   public string SelectedSite
   {
      get { return selectedSite; }
      set
      {
         selectedSite = value;
      }
   }
   public void Submit()
   {
      MessageBox.Show(SelectedSite);
      NavigationManager.Navigate(NavigationKeys.Main);
   }
}
```

This screenshot shows my empty `MessageBox` that should contain the text:

[image: You can see empty value]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `Text` property and set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` for the source property (`SelectedSite`) to get set on each keystroke:

```
<TextBox
    Name="linkTb"   
    Text="{Binding SelectedSite, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                  
    IsManipulationEnabled="True"
    TabIndex="0" />
```

Since the `TextBox` should update the source property, there is no need to pass it as parameter to the command so you can remove this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedSite}"
```